# How to adapt 4th order IIR filter coefficients from matlab to cmsis dsp biquad struct

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response

I'm designing an IIR 4th order filter to be implemented using CMSIS DSP on a cortex-M4 using a direct form II trannsposed structure. I get this coefficient from matlab's "butter" function:(consider Fs = 48kHz, bandpass Fc1 = 445 Hz, Fc2 = 561Hz)

```
b[5.70278412657461e-05   0   -0.000114055682531492   0   5.70278412657461e-05]
a[1   -3.97002047467733   5.9189048757951   -3.92762130007361   0.97875498919531]
```

I know i have to use two stages of a biquad cascade IIR filter and the according structure should receive coefficients in the follow way:

```
float32_t[10] = {b10, b11, b12, a11, a12, b20, b21, b22, a21, a22};
```

Question: Can some tell me how to translate matlab answer into CMSIS struct format?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% design the filter as poles, zeroes and gain
[z,p,k] = butter(2,[445 561]*2/48000);
% turn into biquads
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);
% eliminate a0
coeffs = sos(:,[1 2 3 5 6]);
% make a linear array
coeffs = [coeffs(1,:) coeffs(2,:)];
```